# Reorder GridView with buttons

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `GridView` like this:

```
<GridView SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Bla}" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:BlaType">
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BlaString}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I'm trying to get the `GridView` to allow reordering, but the problem is I have a button and some other stuff inside of the gridview.

The button eats up all the focus, so the `GridView` can't perform any reordering. Is there any way around this? Like to invoke the reorder event manually? Without the button the reordering works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could use `Border` to instead the button to achieve the similar visual effect, besides, the border doesn’t affect the reorder of gridview.

As follows:

```
<GridView SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Bla}" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:BlaType">
            <Border Background="LightGray" Height="30" Width="60" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind BlaString}" />
            </Border>        
         </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```